# Subscript out of range error with array populated from range or listobject - VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate an array with spreadsheet data in a table by assigning the value of the range or listbox databodyrange directly to the array. The size of the array is correct but I can't get the values from the array.  Where am I going wrong?  Do I need to just populate my array iteratively with a loop?

```
dim arrsearch() as variant

'tried both of these...
arrSearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table3").DataBodyRange.Value 
arrSearch = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:C10").Value

Debug.Print LBound(arrSearch) ' this works (it's 1)
Debug.Print uBound(arrSearch) ' this works (it's 7)
Debug.Print arrSearch(6) ' this doesn't work - returns subscript out of range error.
```

Comment: `arrSearch` is a 2D array, not a 1D array. So use `Debug.Print arrSearch(6, 1)`.

Comment: `LBound(arrSearch)` assumes the 1st dimension.  It is the same as `LBound(arrSearch, 1)`

Comment: Try `Debug.Print "1st dim (rows): [" & LBound(arrSearch, 1) & "," & UBound(arrSearch, 1) & "]": Debug.Print "2nd dim (cols): [" & LBound(arrSearch, 2) & "," & UBound(arrSearch, 2) & "]": Debug.Print arrSearch(6, 1)`.

Comment: To clarify, any array obtained from Excel will be a 2D array even if you only asked for a colum or a row.  If you want a single row or colum range to have a single index then you must use the worksheetfunction.transpose method.  e.g. arrSearch = APplication.worksheetfunction.transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:C10").Value)

Comment: ^^^^ One caveat to the `Application.Transpose` is that there is a limit to the size of the array that can be transposed.  Which means that there comes a time that if you want a single dimension array you will need to load the range into a 2d and iterate that and load a 1d array.